# Using \newcommand to define nested commands

Tags: macros

I am relatively new to LaTeX which is why even though I have tried to read up on `\newcommand` and various ways of how to use it, I still can't get the code to work.

Here's the gist of it:
I'm using `\marginpar` a lot for commentary next to text in a scrbook document.

So I redefined it to save time, space and make the code more readable in general like this:
`\newcommand{\sn}[1]{\marginpar{#1}}`
which works fine.

However, I would like all the commentary to be in bold. So I tried:
`\newcommand{\sn}{textbf{\marinpar{#1}}}`
which sadly doesn't work at all.

I have tried various combinations and defining a suitable command via two steps to no avail.

I'm stuck using `\sn{\textbf{Some commentary here}}` which I cannot believe to be the only solution here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!, please approve the answer if it works to close the question.

Answer (score 3):

Hi have you tried with `\newcommand{\sn}[1]{\marginpar{\textbf{#1}}}` ?
i think you was close you just misorder commands and forget the `\`.